# Proving a set is positively invariant for a system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, lyapunov-functions, set-invariance

I have the following system and set S:

$$x' = - y + x - x^3 - xy^2\\y' = y + x - y^3 - x^2y
\\\ S = \{(x, y) \in R^2 : x^2 + y^2 \leqslant \sqrt2 \}$$

I need to prove that for this system, the set S is positively invariant.

My first thought was to find a Lyapunov function.
However, all candidates I tried to use was't suitable to deduce anything.

I would be thankful for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your set $S$ is the closed, circular disc in $\mathbb R^2$ centered on the origin and with radius equal to $\sqrt[4]{2}$. The boundary of $S$ is the circle centered on the origin of radius $\sqrt[4]{2}$.

So, fixing a point $(x,y)$ on that circle, what you need to prove is that the vector $\langle x',y' \rangle$ is pointing *inside* the circle.

At the point $(x,y)$, the vector $\langle x,y \rangle$ is an outward normal of the circle. Therefore, $\langle x',y' \rangle$ points *inside* the circle if and only if the dot product with the outward normal is negative:
$$\langle x',y' \rangle \cdot \langle x,y \rangle < 0
$$
Substituting and simplifying:
\begin{align*}
(-y + x - x^3 - x y^2) x + (y + x - y^3 + x^2 y) y &= x^2 + y^2 - x^4 - 2 x^2 y^2 + y^4 \\
 &= \sqrt[4]{2} - (\sqrt[4]{2})^2 \\
 &< 0
\end{align*}
which finishes the proof.

One can express this in terms of Lyaponov functions, if one wants: $x^2 + y^2$ is a Lyaponov function, because $\langle x,y \rangle$ is equal to ($\frac{1}{2}$ times) the gradient of $x^2 + y^2$. Geometrically, the Lyaponov condition is just saying that the vector $\langle x',y'\rangle$ points inward along each circle $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, which is exactly what my computations prove.